# Pull images from an Azure container registry to a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers

I have followed this tutorial [microsoft_website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes) to pull images from an azure container. My `yaml` successfully creates a pod job, which can pull the image, BUT only when it runs on the `agentpool` node in my cluster.

For example, adding `nodeName: aks-agentpool-33515997-vmss000000` to the `yaml`works fine, but specifying a different node name, e.g. `nodeName: aks-cpu1-33515997-vmss000000`, the pod fails. The error message I get with describe pods is `Failed to pull image` and then `kubelet  Error: ErrImagePull`.

What I'm missing?

Create secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret-name> \
--docker-server=<container-registry-name>.azurecr.io \
--docker-username=<service-principal-ID> \
--docker-password=<service-principal-password>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the node name? Do you have a different namespace and different agent pools? And how do you create the secret?

Comment: two agent pools in the same namespace and cluster. I have updated the question with the code for the secret.

Comment: How did you created the AKS cluster? And what API version it relies on?

Comment: @andov I dont really understand what the problem was, but I think that the problem can be related to the updating of the cluster to kubernetes 1.19.7. This is the only thing that happened after I created and successfully pulled the image for the first time. Fortunately, deleting the old image and creating/pushing a new one solved the problem.

Comment: In this case I advise you to open an incident case to Azure support for AKS from your subscription, where AKS is deployed. The support team has full access to the AKS service backend and they can tell exactly what was causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user1571823 told solution to the problem is deleting the old image from the acr and creating/pushing a new one.
The problem was related to some sort of corruption in the image saved in the azure container registry (acr). The reason why one agent pool could pulled the image was actually because the image already existed in the VM.

Henceforth  as @andov said  it is good option to open an incident case to Azure support for [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/services/kubernetes-service/) from your subscription, where AKS is deployed. The support team has full access to the AKS service backend and they can tell exactly what was causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Four things to check:

- Is it a subscription issue? Are the nodes in different subscriptions?
- Is it a rights issue? Does the service principle of the node have rights to pull the image.
- Is it a network issue? Are the nodes on different subnets?
- Is there something with the image size or configuration, that means that it cannot run on the other cluster.

Edit

New-AzAksNodePool has a parameter -DefaultProfile

It can be AzContext, AzureRmContext, AzureCredential

If this is different between your nodes it would explain the error

Comment: both nodes are in the same subscription and network. The image size shouldnt be a problem. How do I check the rights for the service principle of the nodes? Both nodes are in the same cluster. Can they still have different rights?